# Gamesparks timestamp not working in android pie

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-9.0-pie, gamesparks

Hi i am using gamesparks as backend for my realtime multiplayer game.
Earlier i was getting packets on time and my clock sync worked properly,but from past few weeks i am not getting timestamp packets from gamesparks on devices which have android pie in them.

I tried lowering my API level to 27.

Comment: can you provide us with the code you tried with?

Comment: My code is running perfectly in devices upto Oreo but the problem arises only in pie.

Comment: How will i help you without understanding the codebase or the configurations? You dont have to provide the whole code.. just the code relevant to the question.